Is it possible to install a Linux distro split between two usb drives?
I have 2 USB drives, each 32GB. I was trying to install XFCE version of Debian 12 on one of the 32GB USB drives. But I failed, and then Google said for a complete functional Desktop environment to run, I need at least more than 50 GB of free space. Now my question is whether it was possible to split /home and /root into separate usb drives during installation process. So I tried doing that, I plugged in my 2 usb drives, and tried writing /home to one usb drive and the /root and the rest to another usb drive and it failed the installation saying "Installation failed". I used the normal GUI installation procedure for Debian XFCE during the installation. I was wondering if it was possible to install Linux on 2 separate usb drives


Is it possible to install a Linux distro split between two usb drives?

yes. Is it a good idea? Probably not.

I have 2 USB drives, each 32GB.

32 GB should be plenty for an installation of a modern Linux distro, so why use a second one?

But I failed, and then Google said for a complete functional Desktop environment to run, I need at least more than 50 GB of free space.

Google lies. Especially it's large language model "AI" (artificial, but not really intelligent). And there's a lot of bad websites out there. I have a hunch this wasn't really well-researched.

Now my question is whether it was possible to split /home and /root into separate usb drives during installation process.

Yes; the installer makes this trivially possible (Select "whole disk with LVM", select "Separate /home partition"). But

it's not necessary, 32 GB suffices totally
it's not necessary to do the split "statically". If you're using an LVM scheme, you can simply add additional USB sticks to extend your storage as necessary, instead of having to guess how much space you need for root and /home.

So, don't do that.  Do the installation from the debian netinst iso.
Simply select "Whole disk with LVM", and importantly "All files in one partition".

I'm currently doing this in the background as I type this – on a 20 GB drive, smaller than 32 GB! It works. Whatever went wrong for you: it had nothing to do with a lack of space.
Here's the installed thing: full installation is 5.1 GB of the 18 GB my system assigned for storage:

If you later need to add more space, say, as you start accumulating data, as said, you can just use your second USB drive to extend your LVM volume. It's trivial, and you don't need to think about which data is in which directories.

Sorry for the late reply. That's weird, why did it fail for me then? Also, previously I was able to install headless version of Debian on one of my usb drives without any problems, the problem only comes when I try installing a full fledged desktop environment. Also, I'll try using LVM later at some point today and let you know here.

@randomuser I don't know why it failed for you, you don't describe how it fails. Note that I used the netinstaller image, and chose to install xfce only, and not xfce AND Gnome AND KDE AND cinnamon, which might make a difference.

So, I downloaded a xfce iso of Debian 12 from debian cdimage repo which is 4GB in size and used the gui installer from there. It just says "failed installation process". I necessarily did not check the logs at that time since I was in a hurry. I tried doing the same with a Kali Linux iso image and same results, it just fails on installation process. I'll look into it further more.

well a) try the netinstaller image, said that thrice now, and b) check whether your USB drives are in good shape.

Yep found the problem, it was the usb drive. During installation when it failed on the "Installing system" step, I tabbed onto console 4 with alt+4 and the found multiple lines of "I/O block error". Clearly it's the usb drive, because I emptied out a second usb drive and was able to install a full OS on that drive, no problem at all. Well. that's what I get for buying cheap USB drive.
